# Wordpress wraps span tags into p tags

Tags: functions, admin, hooks, tinymce, editor

I am trying to get rid of the undesired behavior. 
TinyMCE after submitting a post wraps my `<span>` tags into the `<p>` tags.

Here is an example

```
<div class="conten__title-wrapper">
   <h5 class="conten__title">Wordpress</h5>
   <span class="content__icon fa fa-wordpress"></span>
</div>
```

I get the following output instead.

```
<div class="conten__title-wrapper">
   <h5 class="conten__title">Wordpress</h5>
   <p>
      <span class="content__icon fa fa-wordpress"></span>
   </p>
</div>
```

I have tried to solve the problem using the hook `tiny_mce_before_init`, like that.

```
   public function set_admin_hooks()
    {
        add_filter('tiny_mce_before_init', array($this, 'change_mce_options'),1);
    }

    public function change_mce_options($init)
    {
        $init["forced_root_block"] = "h4";
        $init["force_br_newlines"] = true;
        $init["force_p_newlines"] = false;
        $init['valid_children'] = "+a[div|p|ul|ol|li|h1|span|h2|h3|h4|h5|h5|h6]";
        $init["convert_newlines_to_brs"] = true;
        return $init;
    }
```

The hook function is called but it still doesn't affect anyhow on this weird behavior.

Also I can see this options in the output in the bottom of my page (inline Javascript)

```
<script type="text/javascript">
        tinyMCEPreInit = {
......
```

I am working in the `Text Mode`. I am creating all my posts using plain HTML.

What else can I try to get rid of this "awesome feature" ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have investigated this problem and recognized that it is not the TinyMCE fault, but the issue is caused by the the hook function `wpautop` instead. And tags are wrapped just before post is being displayed.
So in order to fix this issue just remove the hook function like that.

```
   remove_filter( 'the_content', 'wpautop' );
```

This could be done for example in your `functions.php` file.